# JSON Parse failed from string of json that coming from Swift conversion

Tags: javascript, ios, json, swift, reactjs

i am curious why my json is not on correct format. i have tried to add a dictionary of array and i figure it out, my json isnt on correct format, ACTIVE_CHATS and INACTIVE_CHATS should be list of array which is i created by .append(value) on swift3. but after i try JSON.parse on my react stringify, i got uncaught json position. I check with android team, figure out that it should be [] instead of () for array.. how do i get correct format for json in swift ?

This is my current json format which is wrong

```
{
    "ACTIVE_CHATS" =     (
    );
    "INACTIVE_CHATS" =     (
                {
            "app_token" = "someapptoken";
            "channel_name" = "Channel-1";
            icon = "https://media.icon.com/icons/appicon-1.jpg";
            "last_message" = "some message";
            "time_since_last_message" = "2017-03-28 06:13:33 +0000";
            "unread_messages" = 3;
        }
    );
    "ALL_CHAT" =     {
        "app_token" = "someapptoken";
        "channel_name" = "Channel-2";
        icon = "https://media.icon.com/icons/appicon-2.jpg";
        "last_message" = "Some message";
        "time_since_last_message" = "2017-03-28 06:13:33 +0000";
        "unread_messages" = 3;
    };
}
```

my code when create the json in swift

```
        var activearray = Array<Any>()
        var inactivearray = Array<Any>()
        var testdict = [String: Any]()
        var counter = 0
        for data in array {
            var listMessage : [Any?] = (Smooch.conversation()?.messages)!
            let unreadMsgCount = Smooch.conversation()?.unreadCount
            if listMessage.count == 0{
                continue
            }
            var iconUrl = ""
            var channelName = ""
            for msg in listMessage {
                let msgSkt = msg as! SKTMessage
                if (!msgSkt.isFromCurrentUser) {
                    iconUrl = (msg as! SKTMessage).avatarUrl!
                    channelName = (msg as! SKTMessage).name!
                    break
                }
            }
            let lastMsg : SKTMessage = listMessage[listMessage.count - 1] as! SKTMessage
            let lastMsgText : String = lastMsg.text!
            let epTime : Date = lastMsg.date!
            var dict = [String: Any]()
            dict = ["unread_messages":unreadMsgCount! as UInt,"icon":iconUrl,"channel_name":channelName,"last_message":lastMsgText,"time_since_last_message":epTime,"app_token":array[counter]]
            if counter == 0 {//put all
                testdict["ALL_CHAT"] = dict
            }else if counter > 0 && unreadMsgCount! > 0{// add active
                activearray.append(dict)
            }else{//add unactive
                inactivearray.append(dict)
            }
            counter += 1
        }

        testdict["ACTIVE_CHATS"] = activearray
        testdict["INACTIVE_CHATS"] = inactivearray
```

Comment: Where are you getting the above output from?

Comment: @Fahim i output my json using nsstring with format from obj-c...
then i parse using JSON.parse from react native got uncaught position JSON, check with json parser also same error.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was what is the source of the original JSON? Is this from an API endpoint? And if yes, then you probably need the JSON to be formatted correctly by the API endpoint ...

Comment: @Fahim oh it is json which i created using dictionary on swift. All of the value data i get from smooch chat API ( but they are not returning json they return single value, i created the json itself from swift by putting it values into a key) then i bridge this dictionary into obj-c to be read by react native part. But somehow the format is not correct i by itself after i create it in swift .. any idea ?

Comment: Can you post the code that you use to create the JSON? Then either I or somebody else can take a look and advice you.

Comment: @Fahim okay edited. i dont know that is swift standart json or not. but that  is how i make the json one..

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think you understood me. What is the code which outputs the JSON you've shown in your question above? The code you've provided creates a Swift dictionary but what is the code for converting the dictionary to the actual JSON output you've shown above?

Comment: aha i see @Fahmi .. wait.. it is on the obj-c code

something like

NSDictionary *dictMap = [self.smooch getConversationsListWithArray:smoochAppToken];
NSString *jsonObj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dictMap];

output coming from jsonObj

Comment: OK, now I see the issue :) See my answer for more details as to what is going on and what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments, the issue you are facing is because you output an `NSDictionary` as its string representation (or description, if you prefer) instead of actually outputting valid JSON :)

What you need to do is to pass the final NSDictionary that you want to convert to JSON format to the `data(withJSONObject:options:)` method of  `JSONSerialization`.

In Swift, the code would look something like this:

```
do {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:testdict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    let str = String(data:data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(str)
} catch {
    print("JSON error")
}
```

Comment: aha i see. Thank you @Fahim !
i was trying this method too but got json invalid and app crash. but now it worked, (maybe i was have wrong code position)